# Force terminate script

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

```
while true; do ./bash -a -f -x; sleep 30; done
```

After `sleep 30` How to force stop ( like `CTRL+C` ) `./bash -a -f -x` and do it again ?

Comment: Why have you named your script `bash`, also why the argument is `script` (is it executable?). Good luck having these early in your `PATH`.

Comment: yes its executable i want it run and after 30 sec force exit and run again .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to understand what you want to have exactly.

Maybe something like this?

```
while true; do timeout 30 ./bash -a -f -x script; done
```